# Using a Class mediator with WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use a class mediator with the WSO2 ESB.

Following is my mediator class.

```
package samples.mediators;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class SiriBankMediator extends AbstractMediator {
    @Override
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        System.out.println("Hurraaaayyyy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return false; 
    }
}
```

As suggested by [Writing a WSO2 ESB Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator), I tried the "Easier Way", created a jar with synapse-core_2.1.0.wso2v8.jar included in class path.

MANIFEST.MF is as follows

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: synapse-core_2.1.0.wso2v8.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_07 (Oracle Corporation)
```

And then as article suggested, dropped the jar to repository/components/lib in the ESB.

But after ESB restart when I try to [load class](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Class+Mediator) it gives the error **Class not found in the path**
[image: Class not found in the path]

Jar file used is shared at [siri.jar](http://www.4shared.com/file/bDZbhKvs/siri.html)

Wonder what is missing in the steps I followed.

Thank you in advance.

Note: I used *WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.5.1*

Comment: Can you just switch to the "source view" and show the code of the sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've successfully deployed your custom mediator using the maven approach. Here's what I've done.

I created the following directory structure and placed your SiriBankMediator.java in src/main/java:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── java
│           └── SiriBankMediator.java
```

The pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.samples.mediator</groupId>
    <artifactId>siribankmediator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
            <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-Incubating-repo</id>
            <name>Maven Incubating Repository</name>
            <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-maven2-repo</id>
            <name>Apache Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.test</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>org.test</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.test.mediator.*,
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *; resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Fragment-Host>synapse-core</Fragment-Host>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.wso2v1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then inside the directory containing the POM file, we do `mvn compile package`. This should build the jar file you need to put inside of `$ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib` in the folder called target.

Finally you can load the class as org.samples.mediator.SiriBankMediator through the carbon management frontend. Don't forget to restart your ESB. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

My Manifest of my Custom Mediator jars look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_27-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

So maybe do not add that classpath and if this does not work, try to build with a Java 1.6 version. 
Then it should all be fine.

Remember add your jar in "components/lib". Check the "components/dropins" folder after startup if WSO2 ESB has created a OSGi bundle of your jar. Then the class should be available.

Answer (score 0):

try with your mediator class package name with at least three letters ,

example : package samples.mediators;

instead of that package name , try, package samples.mediators.anything;

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not useful for you because this was asked like 2 years ago but anyone else came across this issue will be find my answer useful.

Just use package name other than samples.mediators that'll solve this issue. cheers..!